# Why is MongoClient.connect running upwards of 25 times?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I call a function that inputs data into a table the problem is that the function call itself is running many times, here is the code I am running.

```
function showGrab(url){
request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html),
        for(i = 0; i < $('.no_toggle._clearfix').length; i++){
            $('.no_toggle._clearfix').eq(i).filter(function(){
                 //grab all relevant information
            })   
        }

    //this connection is running many times.
    MongoClient.connect(murl, function(err,db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        checkDb(db, function(){
            db.close();
            console.log(10);
            })
        })
    })
}
```

When I run this code I get 10 console logged multiple times, I have made sure its out of the loop and that the function showGrab is only being called once.

```
var checkDb = function(db, callback){
    var cursor = db.collection($$showName).find();
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
       assert.equal(err, null);
       if(doc
       callback();
})
}
```

Even when checkdb is essentially empty i still get the same problem.

Comment: What does checkDB do? Can you show the code?

Comment: Check dB is iterating towards all the datas in the collection so if it has 10 then it will log 10/times.. Look for better code

Comment: What do you mean by datas in the collection? when I changed the code to only input one piece of information I still got the same problem.